# How to determine if compilation debug="true" in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I am drawing a blank here for something that should be simple...

I am trying to do something like:

```
    <my:control runat="server" id="myid" Visible="<%= (is compilation debug mode?) %>" />
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for (did not want to use code behind or directives), but I was able to use in the code behind, code from Nicholas Carey: DebugViewControl.Visible = ((System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(@"system.web/compilation")).Debug;

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This should get you the `<compilation>` element in the `<system.web>` section group:

```
using System.Web.Configuration ;

. . .

CompilationSection compilationSection = (CompilationSection)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(@"system.web/compilation") ;

. . .

// check the DEBUG attribute on the <compilation> element
bool isDebugEnabled = compilationSection.Debug ;
```

Easy!

Comment: So easy, just sent it to a teammate who is trying to turn off his minify code in debug build. Thanks :)

Comment: Why not HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled ?

Comment: @AdrianSalazar in some cases the HttpContext could be null, for exmaple a process running async background thread that are run separately from a context.

Comment: @ErgonomicDeveloper well, please refer to the Question itself. We're rendering a control, not running async code. This thread will have an HttpContext, so I won't worry.

Answer (score 60):

The [`HttpContext.IsDebuggingEnabled` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled(v=vs.110).aspx):

```csharp
using System.Web;

if (HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) { /* ... */ }
```

From the documentation:

> Gets a value indicating whether the current HTTP request is in debug mode[…]
>   `true` if the request is in debug mode; otherwise, `false`.

Comment: available in all .NET versions it looks like.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: but not available in every context e.g. WCF

Answer (score 15):

```
<my:control runat="server" id="myid" Visible="<%= HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled %>" />
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.isdebuggingenabled%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

or
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jan/19/Detecting-ASPNET-Debug-mode with a fruitful feedback below.

Comment: this is not working. I even changed "<%= HttpContext...." to "<%# HttpContext..." to avoid the errors, changed web.config to set compilation debug="false" and ran in release mode, but the control is still visible.

Comment: You have to call DataBind() if you use <%# %> notation.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you can make it work with a

```
#if DEBUG
#endif
```

bit of code in your *ASPX* page, not your code-behind (that's a separate compile).

Something like:

```
<script runat="server" language="C#">
  protected Page_Load() {
#if DEBUG
     myid.Visible = true;
#else
     myid.Visible = false;
#endif
  }
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could us `ConfigurationManager` or `XElement` and actually parse the web.config from code and find the attribute.

For example:

```
var xml = XElement.Load("path-to-web.config");
bool isDebug = (bool)xml.Descendants("compilation").Attribute("debug");
```

Comment: I am not looking for compile time directives

Comment: Sure, the XElement bit has nothing to do with compiler directives.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you could use an IF DEBUG pre-processor directive to set the visibility attribute:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Good article from Phil Haack on this:

http://haacked.com/archive/2007/09/16/conditional-compilation-constants-and-asp.net.aspx#51205

Comment: Yes, that's right. But only in the aspx view, because debug build in the DLL is different than in the web.config.

Comment: Good point, I've added a link above that goes into detail on this :)