# How can I verify debug="false" in web.config via unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, visual-studio-2013

I am using `ASP.NET MVC4`, `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` and `Jenkins`. In my web.config I want to ensure via unit-tests, that the attribute `debug` is set to `false`:

```
<configuration>
[...]
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false">
[...]
```

How can I ensure that, using a unit test?

```
[TestClass]
    public class WebConfigTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// in Web.config, debug mode must be set to 'false'
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestDebugFalse()
        {
            // Arrange

            // Act

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(?, "false");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? typically unit test projects have their own config file.

Comment: If you really want to, I assume you can just read the `web.config` file since it's XML and get the node you want.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193010/how-to-determine-if-compilation-debug-true-in-web-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing configurations like this can give you a false sense of security, because *configurations can be changed post-deployment*. This is unlike the rest of the code that you're unit testing, which would require a recompilation in order for the changes to take effect.

If you still want to have a test for this situation, though, your test will need to manually load the `web.config` file and parse it for the expected value. (You can't use the `ConfigurationManager`, since your test project uses its own `app.config` instead of the `web.config` you're targeting.)

For example:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

[TestClass]
public class WebConfigTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// in Web.config, debug mode must be set to 'false'
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDebugFalse()
    {
        var path        = @"Path to web.config";
        var config      = XDocument.Load(path);

        var compilation = config.XPathSelectElement("/configuration/system.web/compilation");
        if(compilation != null)
        {
            var debug = compilation.Attribute("debug");
            if(debug != null)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual("false", debug.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Joe mentioned in the comments that you can alternatively use the `WebConfigurationManager` to get this information, without the XML parsing. For example:

```
[TestClass]
public class WebConfigTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// in Web.config, debug mode must be set to 'false'
    /// </summary>
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestDebugFalse()
    {
        var path                    = @"Path to web.config";
        var webConfig               = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        var virtualDirectoryMapping = new System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping(webConfig.DirectoryName, true, webConfig.Name);
        var fileMap                 = new System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationFileMap();

        fileMap.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", virtualDirectoryMapping);

        var configuration           = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(fileMap, "/");
        var compilation             = configuration.GetSection("system.web/compilation") as System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection;

        if(compilation != null)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(false, compilation.Debug);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should throw an exception if the attribute doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I've updated the example to accommodate null references returned by `XPathSelectElement` and `Attribute`.

Comment: Nit-pick: "You can't use the ConfigurationManager" - you can use WebConfigurationManager to do this, as an alternative to parsing XML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368748/how-to-openwebconfiguration-with-physical-path

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the info; I was unaware that this existed. I've updated my answer to include the code to use this as an alternative approach.